# How do I transfer protobuf executables

Tags: dll, compilation, protobuf-c

I compiled the project according to the protobuf guidelines, and 'protoc' ran fine locally without any problems. My compile command is as follows

```
export CXXFLAGS=-fPIC
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/protobuf
```

When I transferred everything in the `/usr/local/protobuf`  directory to another machine and used 'protoc' again, the following error occurred

```
./protoc --version
./protoc: symbol lookup error: ./protoc: undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf8compiler20CommandLineInterface12AllowPluginsERKSs
```

I tried adding dynamic library paths to LD_LIBARY_PATH in the new machine directory, but nothing worked: `export LD_LIBARY_PATH=$LD_LIBARY_PATH:/xxx/thirdparty/protobuf/lib`

Will someone please tell me what's going on